# Chemfig error using charge macro: Argument of \charge_c has an extra }

Tags: chemfig

the following code compiles for the first two chemfig macros but not for the third:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    This works: \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]CH_3)(-[6]H)-\charge{120:8pt=\footnotesize{+III}}C(=[1]{\charge{0=\|,90=\|}O})-[7]O-H} 
    
    \bigskip
    
    This works: \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]CH_3)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O-H}
        
    \bigskip
    
    This gives an error:    \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]CH_3)(-[6]H)-\charge{120:8pt=\footnotesize{-I}}C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O-H}
    
\end{document}
```

The third macro gives an error:

```
chemfigtest.tex: Fehler: 14: Argument of \charge_c has an extra }. ...0:8pt=\footnotesize{-I}}C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O-H}
```

I do not see an extra }, so I wonder what's wrong here?

Thanks for helpful hints!

Comment: the \charge command takes two arguments, and while as in your first example you can sometimes leave out the braces around the second argument it is not something you should rely on. With `\charge{120:8pt=\footnotesize{-I}}{C}` your code compiles.

Comment: Now that you point at the braces around the atoms I see them in the manual, but I did not before, forgot the braces and it worked, and I was very confused. Thanks for your pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overlapping with Ulrikes Answer, you missed braces around the atom `C` which should get the charge.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
        
\chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]CH_3)(-[6]H)-%
%
\charge{120:8pt=\footnotesize{-I}}{C}(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O-H }
%                                 | |

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for your helpfulness, too!